# Iframe content height. scrolling iframe content with parent page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

I am trying to add dynamic image gallery to a site I am working on but I am limited to only HTML and css. So I made a separate page on my own server with required php file to create the gallery and used Iframe to load the gallery page to the site.

Problem is now there is two separate scroll bars. one to scroll the content in the iframe and one for the parent page. This makes scrolling on the page very messy. Is there any way so that I can get rid of the scroll bar for the Iframe and be able to scroll through the content within the Iframe from the parent page. Anyway I can make the Iframe behave like a div? I thought the best way would be to set the height of iframe so the height of iframe would change to fit whatever the content that's in it. This way I thought there wouldn't be need for a scroll bar on the iframe.

Here is the gallery page I am trying to load with Iframe http://lejund.com/plugin/#*

I am open to all your suggestions. Is there better way to achieve this other than the Iframe?

Thank you

Comment: adding an onload event to set the iframe's height to the content height is one thing. But I guess the biggest issue is setting the height after the event is fired that loads more images?

Comment: I'm trying to understand the restrictions you have. Do you want your main page non-scrollable while only the iframe scrolls? Can you write javascript for the main page? You may want to bind behavior in the iframe to the scroll event of the parent with $(window).scroll() setting the scrollTop of the iframe... more info please

Comment: The main page (innofeel.kr) I am limited to html javascript and css. I want to add a dynamic image gallery which requires PHP. So what I did was create a gallery page on my server where I don't have php restrictions and used Iframe to load the contents in the main page (innofeel.kr). I want Iframe to have the same height to fit whatever content inside it so I wouldn't need to have a scroll bar on the Iframe. I can use javascript on the main page. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Try `<iframe scrolling="no" style="width: 100%; height: 1060px;" src="http://lejund.com/plugin/index2.html"></iframe>`

the iframe will be **like a part of the page** if this is what You want, 
keep in mind the `scrolling` attribute is not valid in HTML5

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But wouldn't be stop working as soon as content within the iframe exceed the 1060px?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this solution on github by davidjbradshaw.
https://github.com/davidjbradshaw/iframe-resizer

It's using window.postmessage to achieve this.